# Cell Border style with CSS not HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way to set up the inner border or the cell borders of a table with css like you can do with html?

I can only get this far and then have to finish with html for the inner border or the cell borders.

html  `

```
<table class="DrawRow2" table border="1">
<script type="text/javascript">
DR2 ("",Dummy1","Dummy2","Dummy3","Dummy4","Dummy5",1,-1,"Dummy6",1,0,0,"Dummy7");
[ResultItemsHTML]
</script>
</table>
```

css `table.DR2{
                    border:5px; 
                    border-style:outset;
                    border-color:#E80000; width:850px; 
        height:18px;
                    border-spacing:0; 
                    border-collapes:collapse;
    }`

The only way to get the inner border to display is to add the table border="1" is there a way to draw the cell border without having to do it on each tr or td tag?

Comment: float:center is not  write .try this text-align:center; or margin:0 auto;

Comment: bad practice you're right! Doesn't do anything.

Comment: your code is working what you got problem

Comment: I don't want to use table border="" what is it to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css for that

simpply

```
  table {
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  th {
      border: 1px dotted green;
  } 
  td {
      border: 1px dashed red;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
td {
border:solid black 1px;
}
```

Comment: there are no tds that I have tags for.

Comment: it sets the border of a table cell

Comment: The table is automatically drawn by drawing data from a softwares database. I only have access to the table style

Comment: the code I provided is css, not html. you dont need to modify html for it

Comment: There are not td tags in the html all the table cells are drawn from a piece of software look at the code I reposted. All I can style is the table itself and if I take out the table border="1" from `<table class="drawrow2" table border="1"> I loose the inner border. I already have a border set in the css style so is there a way to set the inner border with css?